# angularjs + grunt setup

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have the following directory structure and successfully minified the js files as well as html2js conversion files.

Rightnow,I have 3 files in the final result.

```
js/main.js  // having all the angular modules list
js/app.min.js // one single file having module/factory/controllers
js/template.js // html2js file
```

I am getting an error "module not found".
please suggest me what else I am missing.

**UPDATE**

Please suggest me why below appended file not working ?

```
(function () { 
 'use strict';
  angular
  .module('user', [
    'ui.router'
  ]); 
}());

 (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
   .module('category', [
     'ui.router'
   ]);
 }());

  (function () {
    'use strict';
     angular
     .module('advertise', [
      'ui.router'
    ]);
  }());
```

**UPDATE:** 

 I have successfully merged all the js files into a singe js file. I have followed the order ( module, factory, controller and router in each module ) . minification is not working and so I used the gzip compression to reduce the file size.

Also I have used html2js to cache the templates and seems there is no issues.

Thanks for the support.

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: Are you using strict DI ?

Comment: Can you post your code? It is possible that you are not injecting the dependencies correctly.

Comment: I bet its the classic angular minification issue, either solved by using strict DI, or disabling variables minification ( the former being the superior solution )

Comment: @Slytherin The best option, in my opinion, would be to use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)

Comment: @str I am unfamiliar with that one, seems handy. I got used to strict DI right from my first angular days, so this is not a necessity for me.

Comment: try to use `npm` or `bower` to install the packets